# Matching && and || special character

Tags: java, regex, lucene

I am writing a Lucene application to match `&&` (double ampersand) and `||` (OR or double pipe).

I want to write a regex to match any presence of `&&` and `||` in the input text.

If I write something like below, it only matches for the presence or absence of `&&` not `||`.

```
String inputTextFromFile = "This text contains double ampersand &&, and double pipe || and can this be recognised ? ";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=&&)(?= ||)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputTextFromFile);
```

Please let me know how I could **EXACTLY** match `&&` or `||` in the input text.

Comment: Why *regex* why not `String.contains()` or `indexOf()`?

Comment: Not String contains because I have some more piece of regex, also I am using this on huge files, time efficiency also matters –

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need any regex for that, [`String.contains`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_contains.htm) seems to be sufficient:

```
String str1 = "|| and &&";
boolean hasDoublePipe = str1.contains("||");
System.out.println("Has Double Pipe : " + hasDoublePipe);
boolean hasDoubleAmp = str1.contains("&&");
System.out.println("Has Double Ampersand : " + hasDoubleAmp);
```

You can then check if both boolean variables are `true`, and that is all there is to it.

Output:

```
Has Double Pipe : true
Has Double Ampersand : true
```

**EDIT**:

If you MUST use a regex to check *if both `&&` **OR** `||` must exist in a given string in any order*, you can use this code:

```
String str = "|| and &&";
String rx = "\\|{2}|&&";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
   System.out.println("The string has double pipe or ampersands!");
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/hPF8kv)

And one more sample code that uses capturing groups to cover your scenarios when you have

- Both double ampersands and pipes
- Only double ampersands
- Only double pipes

Code:

```
String str = "&&";
String rx = "(&&.*\\|{2}|\\|{2}.*&&)|(\\|{2})|(&&)";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) != null)
        System.out.println("The string has double pipe and ampersands!");
    else if (m.group(2) != null)
        System.out.println("The string has double pipes!");
    else if (m.group(3) != null)
        System.out.println("The string has double ampersands!");
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/12LojQ)

Comment: Not String contains because I have some more piece of regex, also I am using this on huge files, time efficiency also matters

Comment: @Subramanya - What gives you the idea that *regex* will be faster?. regex was never meant for purposes like this :)

Comment: I am using LUCENE api.. I have tested with the conventional string matching as well as regex.. Regex is much much faster

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get you. I want my regex to match if any double ampersand or double pipe is present in the input text.

Comment: @Subramanya: Ok, I added some more sample code. Basically, in order to just check a full string, we need to consume it, otherwise a look-ahead will be slowly checking each position. With `.*$` we make sure we quickly consume the whole string (if there are newlines, just add a `(?s)` at the beginning of a pattern). That is why I added a modification of your regex: [`(?=.*&&)(?=.*\\|{2}).*$`](https://ideone.com/DjJxMh).

Comment: @stribizhev thank you. but this works only if both are present. My cases would be 1. presence of only && 2. Presence of only || 3. presence of both of them

Comment: @stribizhev  Thank you. Works as required.

Comment: I added the code to show how to check your 3 scenarios.

Comment: @stribizhev Thank you very much, yep I tested all the scenarios and it works well!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[|]{2}|&&");
```

See [Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/aN9cQ5)